# Installing and running MySql on FreeBSD

Tags: mysql, freebsd

Yet for a while I trying to install and run MySql on FreeBSD rooter that We using at office.

I am totally beginner in Linux OS and I do not know what could go wrong on My installation,
So please have a patient whit me,
Here is some copy and paste text from Putty if someone had similar problems please help

```
pppp-ac-01# uname -a
FreeBSD pppp-ac-01.robotsarajevo.com 6.1-RELEASE FreeBSD 6.1-RELEASE #0: Sun May  7 04:32:43 UTC 2006     root@opus.cse.buffalo.edu:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  i386

pppp-ac-01# mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.15 Distrib 6.0.11-alpha, for portbld-freebsd6.1 (i386) using  5.0

pppp-ac-01# mysql -U root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Comment: Check if your mysql process can write in /tmp

Comment: I hope you are aware that you're running a bleeding edge version of MySQL. If you're using the MySQL for anything important, I'd highly recommend to switching to the more stable 5.0 series :)

Comment: Actually you probably want mysql-5.1.x which is the latest general release. Also BSD7 runs Mysql much faster then BSD6 though if your machine is just a single CPU you probably won't notice a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally that just means that `mysqld` isn't running.  Try `invoke-rc.d mysql start`.

Comment: Thanx a lot,
some how in /etc/rc.conf i had a tow times line mysql_enable="YES"
After I clear on line and call
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql-server start
Now I have running mysql.

Comment: There's no invoke-rc.d on FreeBSD – at least not on my system – but if you find the correct rc.d dir, there should be a shell script. For packages installed through ports, it is usually the /usr/local/etc/rc.d